# Trigonometric equation inversion

Tags: trigonometry

I am trying to invert the following equation to have it with $\theta$ as the subject:

$y = \cos \theta \sin \theta - \cos \theta -\sin \theta$

I tried both standard trig as well as trying to reformulate it as a differential equation (albeit I might have chosen an awkward substitution). Nothing seems to stick and I keep on ending up with pretty nasty expressions. Any ideas?

Comment: [Wolfram](http://tinyurl.com/c2gwed8) can help: $±cos^{-1}(\frac{\sqrt{\theta+1}}{\sqrt2}-\frac12 \sqrt{-2 \theta-2 \sqrt2 \sqrt{\theta+1}-1}+1/2)$

Comment: In my view words like "tricky" don't belong in the title -- that's a very subjective assessment. (I like your use of "subject", though :-)

Comment: @draks: I think you wanted $y$ there instead of $\theta$?

Comment: @joriki: you're absolutely right - edited the title to keep it as factual as possible.

Comment: @joriki ah right, sorry can't edit that anymore

Comment: @draks: thanks, I'll check that (I also think that should be $y$). Just wondering whether there were any more "agile" expressions

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$$y = \cos \theta \sin \theta - \cos \theta -\sin \theta$$

$$y - \cos \theta \sin \theta = -\cos \theta -\sin \theta$$

$$y^2 - 2y\cos \theta \sin \theta +\cos^2\theta\sin^2\theta= 1+2\cos \theta \sin \theta$$

$$y^2 - y\sin(2\theta) +\frac14\sin^2(2\theta)= 1+\sin(2\theta)$$

This is a quadratic equation for $\sin(2\theta)$ that you can solve.

Comment: That works! Brilliant, thank you.

Answer (score 2):

Rewrite the equation as $(1-\cos\theta)(1-\sin\theta)=1+y.$

Now make the Weierstrass substitution $t=\tan(\theta/2)$. It is standard that 
$\cos\theta=\frac{1-t^2}{1+t^2}$ and $\sin\theta=\frac{2t}{1+t^2}$. So our equation becomes 
$$\frac{2t^2}{1+t^2}\cdot \frac{(1-t)^2}{1+t^2}=1+y.$$
Take the square root, and clear denominators. We get
$$\sqrt{2}t(1-t)=\sqrt{1+y}(1+t^2).$$
This is a quadratic in $t$.